# How to get value of input type=month in angular

Tags: angular, input, monthcalendar

```
<input value="2019-10" type="month">
```

how to get the value of this input field in angular and how to change the value of input field dynamically??

Comment: Your question lakes details about what you're going to do, but this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47529327/angular-4-get-input-value

Answer (score 1):

use angular data-binding.

```
<input type="month" [(ngModel)]="myVariable">
```

This myVariable you can give starting value and get changed value, when input changes.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do it in .ts file?

Comment: declare myVariable in .ts file. this variable will contain required value.

Comment: when I add [(ngModel)] = "myVariable" in my .html file code crash that url stop opening

Comment: Your probably need to import the formsModule in your app.module. (Inside the imports array)