# how to get input type number's value before submitting

Tags: javascript, html, angular, data-binding

i need to increase product rate qith respect to quantity added ..(in angular 11)

the code ,

```
  <h2>Price: {{price}}</h2> // like {{price*input.value}}
      <h2> Quantity : <div class="number-input">
        <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()" >-</button>
        <input class="quantity" min="0" max="25" name="quantity" value="1" type="number">
        <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()" class="plus">+</button>
      </div>
    </h2>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi there, I strongly advise you take a basic Angular course before jumping in to building forms. There are simple Angular Forms systems to handle what you're doing here, and you'll need to understand those before building anything. SO will be here for when you get stuck, but you need to take the first steps yourself.

Comment: In Angular you don't "get" an input's value. You _bind_ the input to a variable with `[(ngModel)]`, so you already have the value available in your code. Also `click=`, `querySelector` and all these things have nothing to do in an Angular app. As suggested above, you should really learn the basics with a few tutorials :)